# Applescript Infinite Repeat Keystrokes hangs up applications

Tags: applescript

So for an infinite monkey theorem test i need applescript to input random numbers (0-6) into TextEdit.
I have a working code which doesn't slow down the cpu or anything, but i can't terminate it after running it once without terminating TextEdit.

So my question is:
How can i improve this code so it allows me to terminate it without any concerns.

```
delay 2
repeat
    delay 0.2
    tell application "System Events"
        if (item 1 of (get name of processes whose frontmost is true)) is "TextEdit" then
            set r to (random number from 0 to 1)
            if (r = 0) then
                keystroke "0"
            else if (r = 1) then
                keystroke "1"
            end if
        end if
    end tell
end repeat
```

Comment: I suggest anyone debugging this use a `repeat n times` block. I just spent 10 minutes trying to shut this script down.

Comment: :/ that's what the problem real is all about :3

Comment: When I use keystrokes even without a loop, I am seeing that my script is hanging.  @teegabel, Did you get a solution to your problem?

Answer (score 0):

It will take a long time to create a large sample with a .2 delay and keystrokes.

Try something like this:

```
set csvOutputPath to (POSIX path of (path to desktop as text)) & "test.txt"
set fileRef to (open for access csvOutputPath)
close access csvOutputPath

set numberList to {}
set counter to 0
repeat
    set end of numberList to (random number from 0 to 1)
    set counter to counter + 1
    if (counter mod 10000) = 0 then
        write (numberList as text) to csvOutputPath starting at eof
        set numberList to {}
    end if
end repeat
```

Comment: Well what i really try is to run keystrokes through different applications aswell so i really need to use keystroke. I'm trying to search for patterns in different games using different number generators, but i really need to use keystroke. Thanks so much for helping though!